# Infinite Ajax Scroll: Hide parent container of load more button if last

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using [Infinite Ajax Scroll](https://docs.infiniteajaxscroll.com/) for pagination on my blog. When there are no more posts left to load, I want to hide the `trigger` (the buttons) parent container (currently, it just has `opacity: 0`, but this leaves unwanted whitespace).

In the console, I can see that `IAS` leaves a message saying "No more pages left to load", so I know there is a method in place to check if more posts exist. But, having applied two methods, I cannot get it to work.

Method 1: Using `last:function()`
Method 2: Checking if the `trigger` has `opacity: 0`, then hiding parent container if so

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll@3.0.0-beta.6/dist/infinite-ajax-scroll.min.js"></script>


<div class="container pagination-hide">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="pagination">
        <a class="loadmore">Load more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

$(function() {

  var ias = new InfiniteAjaxScroll('.insertPosts', {
    item:       '.insertCard',
    pagination: '.blog-pagination',
    next:       '.next-posts-link',
    trigger:    '.loadmore',
    loadOnScroll: false,
    last:function(){
      $(".pagination-hide").addClass("d-none");
    }
  });

  // $('.loadmore').click(function(){
  //   if ( $(this).css('opacity') == '0' ) {
  //     console.log("true");
  //     $(this).parent(".pagination-hide").addClass("d-none");
  //   }
  // });


});

</script>
```

Have also tried the following, as per [IAS docs](https://docs.infiniteajaxscroll.com/reference/options#trigger), however, this just adds the `d-none` class to `pagination-hide` on page load, rather than adding the class (as it should) if there are no more posts to load.

```js
trigger: {
  element: '.loadmore',
  
  // this function is called when the button has to be hidden
  hide: function(element) {
    $(element).closest(".pagination-hide").addClass("d-none");
    element.style.opacity = '0'; // default behaviour
  }
  
},
```

Comment: Did you try: `display: none`? Also, do you select the most parent element if the block you want to hide? Both can help you here.

Comment: Hi @DennisvandeHoef - Yes, I have also tried `.css("display","none")` instead of `addClass("d-none")`, it doesn't apply the css (nor does the class get added). Not sure what you mean with the latter end of your message? The element I'm trying to hide is `.pagination-hide`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you would also need to add a show() method that un-does the changes in hide(), in order to get the correct behavior:

```js
trigger: {
  element: '.loadmore',
  
  // this function is called when the button has to be hidden
  hide: function(element) {
    $(element).closest(".pagination-hide").addClass("d-none");
    element.style.opacity = '0'; // default behaviour
  },
  
  show: function(element) {
    $(element).closest(".pagination-hide").removeClass("d-none");
    element.style.opacity = '1';
  }
  
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you went on a bad road. You shoud show button `<a class="loadmore">Load more</a>` if you have some other conten unstead of hiding unnecessary. It's wrong in root. You are calling unnecessary operations in the DOM render. You better rewrite your code.

Comment: This may be a correct assessment of the code above but it would help if you provided some simple examples of where things are wrong in the current implementation and how you might go about fixing it? or just post how you might fix some of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT you were on the right track with your first attempt - [the `last` event](https://docs.infiniteajaxscroll.com/reference/events#last) seems like exaclty the right way to do what you need.  But the docs also show that [you need to bind event handlers with `.on()`](https://docs.infiniteajaxscroll.com/reference/events#working-with-events), not pass them as options, which is what you tried.

For example, something like this:

```
var ias = new InfiniteAjaxScroll('.insertPosts', {
    // ... your options
    // last:function(){} // <-- won't work, not the way to bind event handlers
});

// What we want to happen when we've hit the last page
function noMorePages() {
    $(".pagination-hide").addClass("d-none");
}

// Handle the "last" event with our function
ias.on('last', noMorePages);
```

There is [a similar example in the docs](https://docs.infiniteajaxscroll.com/advanced/last-page-message).

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to provide `show` and `hide` functions for the trigger [ref](https://docs.infiniteajaxscroll.com/reference/options#trigger). The library calls the functions automatically on last event.
Demo website https://zyf5k.csb.app/

Codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-volhard-zyf5k?file=/index.js

Code for ready reference:

```js
window.ias = new InfiniteAjaxScroll(".container", {
  item: ".item",
  next: nextHandler,
  trigger: {
    element: ".loadmore",
    show: function (element) {
      element.parentElement.style.display = "block";
    },

    hide: function (element) {
      //hide desired element`
      element.parentElement.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
});
```

Note: Didn't realize @Kevin had already answered this. Posting the answer for extra info.

Answer (score 0):

so this works for me:

```js
 infiniteScrollInstance.on('load', function(response) {
        if(!infiniteScrollInstance.canLoad)
        {
            const loadMoreCont = document.querySelector(".news-list-view .load_more_cont");
            loadMoreCont.remove();
        }
    });
```